# Leaflet map with geojson data. Popup with no information

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, geojson, markers

I created a map in Leaflet and I have `GeoJSON` data. I added my data to my map. But on the map, there are only points with no information when I click on them. I tried to add use this **:**

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();
```

But it didn't work either. Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the popup with information while creating the GeoJSON layer:

```
L.geoJSON(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Look for more infos into the [GeoJSON Tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/examples/geojson/)